# Swiper: change background-color of body depending on the slide

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, swiper.js

I am using [Swiper's Loop Mode](https://swiperjs.com/demos/#loop_mode_infinite_loop) to have a slide with pagination and navigation.

What I would like to do is change the background-color of `body`, depending on the slide the user is at (so, say, I am on slide 2, body background-color is #FFF, I am on slide 3, it is #000, etc).

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-demo-20-loop-mode-infinite-loop-nre2qw) listen transitions  and change background related to index of slide

```
swiper.on('transitionEnd', function (e) {
      if(this.activeIndex==2){
        document.querySelector(".swiper-slide-active").style.background = 'red';
      }
 });
```